# New to Ubuntu and got stuck on managing internet conection

Tags: 12.04, networking, internet

Just installed Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS and got stuck on the part connecting to the internet.
I can't even find a guide that can help me find the problem.

Maybe it's because I'm new and I just can't find the right way to do it, or Ubuntu didn't install eth-drivers.

I have a router that gives away automatically IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to have problems like this. What kind of router are you using ?

-> basic Net drivers drivers for connection to internet, are standard packed  in Ubuntu, maybe you need to try to get in the router.   (exp 192.168.0.1 and manually apply some changes)